# Error trying to parse imaginary programming language

Tags: ocaml, ocamllex, menhir

I'm working on a language interpreter for a programming language I made up. Here's some example code, which should work but currently dies with `Syntax error at offset 45.` when reading this testcase.

```
{
  foo = { "min" : 1 ,"max" : 5};
  foo["min"]
}
```

The correct interpretation is for the first line with foo to create a map and store it in a variable named foo, the second line looks up the value of the field min in the record foo, and the starting/ending curlies together with the semicolon wrap the two expressions into an `expr_seq` (i.e. a block) which evaluates to the same thing as the last `expr` in it.

A simplified version of my parser.mly is as follows:

```
%token <int> INT
%token <string> VAR
%token SEMI COMMA COLON ASSIGN QUOTE
%token LBRACK RBRACK LCURL RCURL
%token EOF

%start <int> main

%%

main:
| EOF
    { failwith "empty input" }
| e = exp EOF
    { e }

exp:
| INT
    { 0 }
| e = exp LBRACK v = q_var RBRACK
    { (* map lookup *) 0 }
| v = VAR ASSIGN e = exp
    { (* assign to var *) 0 }
| v = VAR LBRACK f = q_var RBRACK ASSIGN e = exp
    { (* assign to map field *) 0 }
| v = VAR
    { Printf.printf "lookup %s\n" v; 0 }
| LCURL e = expr_seq RCURL
    { (* Block expression *) 0 }
| LCURL f = fields RCURL
    { (* map literal *)0 }

fields:
| v = q_var COLON e = exp
    { [(v, e)] }
| v = q_var COLON e = exp COMMA vt = fields
    { (v, e) :: vt }

q_var:
| QUOTE v = VAR QUOTE
    { Printf.printf "qvar %s\n" v; v }

expr_seq:
| e = exp
    {[e]}
|e1 = exp SEMI e2 = expr_seq
    {e1 :: e2}
```

Trying to debug it on my own, I found that if you removed the following `| v = VAR LBRACK f = q_var RBRACK ASSIGN e = exp` it will parse it and run correctly, but I'd really like to be able to set things in maps.

I'm 98% confident that the problem lies in my mly file, but a simplified version of my lexer.mll is as follows:

```
{
  open Parser
  open Printf
}

rule token = parse
| [' ' '\t' '\n']
    { token lexbuf }
| "="
    {ASSIGN}
| ['1'-'9']['0'-'9']* as i
    { INT (int_of_string i) }
| ['a'-'z']+ as v
    { printf "var %s\n" v;VAR v }
| '{'
    { LCURL }
| '}'
    { RCURL }
| '['
    { printf "["; LBRACK }
| ']'
    { printf "]"; RBRACK }
| ';'
    { SEMI }
| ':'
    { COLON }
| ','
    { COMMA }
| '"'
    { QUOTE }
| eof
    { EOF }
| _
    { raise (Failure (sprintf "At offset %d: unexpected character.\n" 
                       (Lexing.lexeme_start lexbuf))) }
```

And a simple ml file is:

```
open Core.Std
open Printf

let rec read_all ic =
  try
    let ln = input_line ic in
      ln ^ read_all ic
  with End_of_file -> "";;

let () =
  let linebuf = Lexing.from_string (read_all stdin) in
  try
    Parser.main Lexer.token linebuf;
    printf "Done"
  with
  | Failure msg ->
      fprintf stderr "%s%!" msg
  | Parser.Error ->
      fprintf stderr "Syntax error at offset %d.\n%!"   
        (Lexing.lexeme_start linebuf)
```

Edit: Here's a Makefile. parser.mly, lexer.mll, and interpreter.ml are the second, third, and fourth files above.

```
all: HB lexer.cmx parser.cmx interpreter.cmx
    @true

HB: interpreter.cmx
    ocamlfind ocamlopt -o HB -linkpkg -package core -package core_kernel \
    -thread -w -10 parser.cmx lexer.cmx interpreter.cmx

interpreter.cmx: lexer.cmx
    ocamlfind ocamlopt -package core -package core_kernel -thread -w   -10 \
    -c interpreter.ml

lexer.cmx: lexer.ml parser.cmx
    ocamlfind ocamlopt    -c lexer.ml

parser.cmx: parser.mly
    menhir --ocamlc "ocamlfind ocamlc" --infer --base parser  parser.mly
    ocamlfind ocamlc -c parser.mli
    ocamlfind ocamlopt -c parser.ml

lexer.ml: lexer.mll
    ocamllex lexer.mll

clean:
    @rm HB *.o *.cmi *.cmx lexer.ml parser.ml parser.mli 2>/dev/null || true
```

and here's making / running it, where test.in is the first one above.

```
$ mk;HB < test.in
ocamllex lexer.mll
menhir --ocamlc "ocamlfind ocamlc" --infer --base parser  parser.mly
15 states, 286 transitions, table size 1234 bytes
Warning: 3 states have shift/reduce conflicts.
Warning: 3 shift/reduce conflicts were arbitrarily resolved.
ocamlfind ocamlc -c parser.mli
ocamlfind ocamlopt -c parser.ml
ocamlfind ocamlopt    -c lexer.ml
ocamlfind ocamlopt -package core -package core_kernel -thread -w -10 \
    -c interpreter.ml
ocamlfind ocamlopt -o HB -linkpkg -package core -package core_kernel \
    -thread -w -10 parser.cmx lexer.cmx interpreter.cmx
Syntax error at offset 45.
var foo
var min
qvar min
var max
qvar max
var foo
[var min
]qvar min
```

Edit 2: I ended up just adding `| e = VAR LBRACK v = q_var RBRACK
    { GetMap(v,LookupVar(e)) }`
 as a special case to my parser. So, problem solved?

Comment: I don't feel like I can help you because your example is too large to understand in the time I have, while simultaneously being unusable as actual source code that I could run through the toolchain. Best would be to get your problem stripped down to something very small. Second best would be to give actual code that shows your problem.

Comment: Usualy a good way to understand problems with grammars is to pass it to `menhir --interpreter` and look at the derivations.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield: Added a Makefile and explained how to run it. The code above is about as stripped down as I can get it, the testcase is parsed corectly if you remove the `(* assign to map field *)` and breaks further if you remove the rest.

Comment: @PierreChambart: Typing `LCURL VAR ASSIGN LCURL QUOTE VAR QUOTE COLON INT COMMA QUOTE VAR QUOTE COLON INT RCURL SEMI VAR LBRACK QUOTE VAR QUOTE RBRACK RCURL` which is the correct interpretation of the test case into `menhir --interpret` prints `ACCEPT`. Is there a way to get menhir to vomit out what tokens it had already matched when it dies?

Comment: Adding a bunch of print statements makes it print out `Syntax error at offset 45.
LCURL VAR ASSIGN LCURL QUOTE VAR QUOTE COLON INT COMMA QUOTE VAR QUOTE COLON INT RCURL SEMI VAR LBRACK QUOTE VAR QUOTE RBRACK RCURL`, which should be accepted since it's the same as what I typed into `menhir --interpret`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking back at this, I believe the reason it doesn't work is that the grammar is not LR(1) and therefore cannot be parsed accurately by Menhir. Determining if `foo["min"]` is the start of `v = VAR LBRACK f = q_var RBRACK ASSIGN e = exp` or is `e = exp LBRACK v = q_var RBRACK`, requires us to lookahead four or so symbols and Menhir as an LR(1) parser only looks ahead one.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to play with your language, and now I agree with a parser, your input is bad, look at your "assign to map field" rule:

```
v = VAR LBRACK f = q_var RBRACK ASSIGN e = exp
```

if we remove this noisy variables (that you don't need to use, btw):

```
VAR LBRACK q_var RBRACK ASSIGN exp
```

that means that rule expects:

```
VAR, '[' '"' VAR '"' ']' '=' exp
```

for example

```
foo["min"] = 42
```

the following is perfectly accepted

```
{
  foo = { "min" : 1 ,"max" : 5};
  foo["min"] = 42
}
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion, but it didn't change the output.

Comment: Ok, looks like you parser is correct, your input wasn't well formed

Comment: The rule I'm trying to match with the `foo["min"]` is `| e = exp LBRACK v = q_var RBRACK
    { (* map lookup *) 0 }` which is supposed to work the same way as it would for python dicts, where it looks up the value in the map.

Comment: The `["min"]` part matches the `LBRACK q_var RBRACK` in the trivial way, the foo matches the `v = VAR` rule and then is the `e = exp` at the beginning. If you remove the "assign to map field" rule, my parser matches it without complaint.